# Iptables udp port forwarding

Tags: iptables, nat, forwarding

I'm using latest debian relese and i need to do some port forwarding, but i dont know how.I have 2 stream sources coming to my server on the same udp port from 2 diferent ip-s

```
192.168.1.2:1003 via udp to 192.168.1.4 (server)  
192.168.1.3:1003 via udp to 192.168.1.4 (server)
```

My qestion is: how to forward this port 1003 coming from 1.2 to some other port 1004 for example?

Comment: similar, but I can't find my answer in that topic. With this rule i can block that port coming from 1.2 but i dont know how to forward..iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.2 -i eth0 -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 1003 -j DROP

Comment: You could later re-ask this question by reformulating so that you exactly explain what is your *UDP-specific* specific problem.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the `PREROUTING` chain to forward port :

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -i eth0 -d 192.168.1.2 --dport 1003 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2:1004
```

By the way, it seems filter is happening directly on the target host, so you could use `REDIRECT` in that case :

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d 192.168.1.2 -p udp --dport 1003 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1004
```

---

In both case, don't forget to allow traffic on port `UDP/1004` after NAT (assuming `UDP/1003` is already allowed) :

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -p udp -d 192.168.1.2 --dport 1004 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```